# Running an UPDATE query within MySQL (with relationships)

Tags: mysql, sql

Some of you will have seen me trying to learn how to run UPDATE queries on MySQL (for those of you who helped out - THANK YOU).  However, whilst progress has certainly been made, I am still struggling to simply update one column with data from another - and can't get it to work.

If I run the following SELECT query, I see several thousand records that match

```
SELECT
`agr_addressbook`.`gtxr2_product_family` AS `gtxr2_product_family`,
`gtxuk_r2_machine`.`product_family` AS `product_family`
FROM (((`agr_addressbook`
JOIN `agr_addressbook_extra` ON ((`agr_addressbook`.`contact_id` = `agr_addressbook_extra`.`contact_id`)))
JOIN `gtxuk_machine` ON ((`agr_addressbook_extra`.`contact_value` = `gtxuk_machine`.`machine_id`)))
JOIN `gtxuk_r2_machine` ON ((CONVERT(`gtxuk_machine`.`machine_desc` USING utf8) = `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`machine_desc`)))
WHERE (`agr_addressbook_extra`.`contact_name` = 'mac_type')
```

However, when I run the following update query - it doesn't update a single value - meaning that I have messed up somewhere:

```
UPDATE agr_addressbook ea 
JOIN agr_addressbook_extra eae ON eae.contact_id = ea.contact_id
JOIN gtxuk_machine hm ON hm.machine_id = eae.contact_value
JOIN gtxuk_r2_machine hrm ON hrm.machine_desc = CONVERT(hm.machine_desc USING utf8)
SET ea.gtxr2_product_family = hrm.product_family
WHERE eae.contact_name = 'mac_type'
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thank you (yet again).

Answer (score 0):

This (or something very similar) might work:

```
UPDATE agr_addressbook ea 
SET ea.gtxr2_product_family = (
SELECT hrm.product_family FROM agr_addressbook_extra eae 
JOIN gtxuk_machine hm ON hm.machine_id = eae.contact_value
JOIN gtxuk_r2_machine hrm ON hrm.machine_desc = CONVERT(hm.machine_desc USING utf8) 
WHERE eae.contact_name = 'mac_type' AND eae.contact_id = ea.contact_id)
```

Your problem may have to do with the way that UPDATE parameters work. Think about how you are passing a JOINed table as the table to perform changes to.

Comment: Thanks for that (makes some sense), but it came up with the error: You can't specify target table 'agr_addressbook' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @AndyDB Yes, try that. Now the table is not being "targeted" but only referenced at the end there. Good luck.